# Problem loading images from DCIM folder in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, filesystems

Good day!

There is a class with the help of which data from folders is read in the special case of DCIM

```
fun loadPhoto(directory: String): List<String> {
val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(directory)
val photos: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory) {
    val images = dir.listFiles()
    if (images != null) {
        for (image in images) {
            if (image.isDirectory) {
                loadPhoto(image.absolutePath)
            } else {
                photos.add(image.absolutePath)
            }
        }
    }
}
return photos
```

}

The path to the folder is set using

```
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory((Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)),"hello.jpg")
```

Then during the test, the file name returns correctly ... When testing this method, it drops out InvocationTargetException

I rummaged through a bunch of different sites, everywhere a solution similar to mine. What could be my problem?

In the manifest, permissions are set

Thanks to everyone who thanks a lot

Comment: "When testing this method, it drops out InvocationTargetException" -- please edit your question and post the entire stack trace. "In the manifest, permissions are set" -- that is insufficient for accessing [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) on most devices. On Android 6.0 through Android 9, you also need to request permissions at runtime. On Android 10+, you need to stop thinking in terms of files, as you do not have access to this directory by default, even with permissions.

Comment: @CommonsWare That is, starting with Android 10, applications in which work with the file system will not work?

Comment: Android 10 [restricts access to external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html) via filesystem APIs. For your own content, you can [store](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/21/scoped-storage-stories-storing-mediastore.html) and [retrieve](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/29/scoped-storage-stories-reading-mediastore.html) from the `MediaStore`. For accessing other apps' content, primarily use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to allow the user to choose the content, wherever it may reside.